# JSF2 error [org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage] Error Rendering View[//WEB-INF/*.xhtml]: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: spring, jsf-2, richfaces, spring-webflow, myfaces

I have an error in Jboss 7.0.2 Arc, JSP 2.1(Myfaces), Richfaces 4,
this is my web.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"          xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">

  <!-- Log4j configurated in spring!!!, 
  before any code directly calling log4j (calling through commons logging doesn't count)? Jing Xue -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j-webapp.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jRefreshInterval</param-name>
    <param-value>1000</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>myWebapp-instance-root</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>

    <display-name>richfaces-application</display-name>
    <!-- Listener para crear el Spring Container compartido por todos los Servlets y Filters (WebApplication Context)-->
    <context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>
    classpath*:META-INF/spring/spring-master.xml
    WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml
</param-value>
    </context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
    <!-- For JSF -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
    <!-- Jboss not use it bundle integrated JSF -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.jboss.jbossfaces.WAR_BUNDLES_JSF_IMPL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Facelets, tell JSF to use Facelets -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.VIEW_HANDLERS</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring JavaServiceFaces framework ApacheMyfaces --> 
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Spring Security, for all -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

    <!-- RichFaces Framework -->
<context-param>
<param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
<param-value>blueSky</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- For control of skins -->
<context-param>
<param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING_CLASSES</param-name>
<param-value>enable</param-value>
</context-param>

    <!-- Servlets for JSF-->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Servlet for Dispatcher of flows -->
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>transportes</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/transportes-servlet.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
 <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup> 
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>transportes</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/flows/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Servlet register for SpringFaces, SpringJavaScript -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.js.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Page That control SpringWeb -->

   <welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/flows/inscripcion/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   </web-app>
```

and the error:

```
12:58:15,480 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.util.ExternalSpecifications] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-2) MyFaces Unified EL support enabled
    12:58:15,596 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/projvehimerc]] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-2) No state saving method defined, assuming default server state saving
    12:58:15,737 SEVERE [org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-2) Error Rendering View[//WEB-INF/flows/inscripcion/login.xhtml]: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewStateManager.saveView(FlowViewStateManager.java:181) [spring-faces-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1554) [myfaces-impl-2.1.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:281) [myfaces-impl-2.1.1.jar:]
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:59) [myfaces-api-2.1.1.jar:]
        at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewHandler.renderView(FlowViewHandler.java:99) [spring-faces-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:85) [myfaces-impl-2.1.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:239) [myfaces-impl-2.1.1.jar:]
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191) [myfaces-api-2.1.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:343) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:90) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:188) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237) [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167) [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:139) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.NamingValve.invoke(NamingValve.java:57) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:154) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:667) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:952) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_25]

    12:58:15,766 SEVERE [org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.ErrorPageWriter] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-2) An exception occurred: javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.wrap(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:241) [myfaces-impl-2.1.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:156) [myfaces-impl-2.1.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:258) [myfaces-impl-2.1.1.jar:]
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191) [myfaces-api-2.1.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:343) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:90) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:188) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237) [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167) [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:139) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.NamingValve.invoke(NamingValve.java:57) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:154) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:667) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:952) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_25]
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewStateManager.saveView(FlowViewStateManager.java:181) [spring-faces-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1554) [myfaces-impl-2.1.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:281) [myfaces-impl-2.1.1.jar:]
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:59) [myfaces-api-2.1.1.jar:]
        at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewHandler.renderView(FlowViewHandler.java:99) [spring-faces-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:85) [myfaces-impl-2.1.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:239) [myfaces-impl-2.1.1.jar:]
        ... 44 more
```

Comment: Please share the full stacktrace.

Comment: this is my full prompt : https://rapidshare.com/files/2875600858/log14.zip

Comment: Please edit your question to include the trace. No one is going to download and extract some external file. It is also not a reliable resource for the case one comes back after one year to read the question/answers.

Comment: I guest the error is  Error Rendering View[//WEB-INF/flows/inscripcion/login.xhtml]: java.lang.NullPointerException, The double slash??? (//)

Comment: In this way include the trace???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the root cause (the bottommost part of the trace):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewStateManager.saveView(FlowViewStateManager.java:181) [spring-faces-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:]
```

The [1st Google hit on this line](http://www.google.com/search?q=java.lang.NullPointerException%20at%20org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewStateManager.saveView) leads us to [SWF bug report 1461](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SWF-1461). This is apparently an acknowledged bug in SWF 2.3.0. According to the linked bug report, it's been fixed in SWF 2.3.1. So, upgrading should do.

Comment: Well really the SWF, that fixed this is          <version>2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>, thnks without yor help I can't solved this quickly.